# Real Analysis Convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functional-analysis

My question is: For $f_n, g, h \in L^p(X)$, where $X$ is a finite measure space,  if $f_n$ converges to $g$ a.e and $f_n$ converges to $h$ weakly in $L^p$, can we conclude any relationship between $g$ and $h$? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This may be a sledgehammer and is only a partial answer for the case when $1<p<\infty$.

Here are three facts:

1) Weakly convergent sequences are norm bounded (see for instance page 255 of [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=wCHtLumoGY4C&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=weak+convergence+bounded&source=bl&ots=vuOaeOri6m&sig=97x5YD8PDNI0X85YJIweicrt8Is&hl=en&sa=X&ei=32ggT6irIYHmggfq0524CQ&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=weak%20convergence%20bounded&f=false) ).

2) For $1<p<\infty$,  norm bounded sequences that converge pointwise a.e. are weakly convergent to their pointwise limit (see, e.g, Theorem 13.44 in Hewitt and Stromberg's, *Real and Abstract Analysis*).

3)Weak limits are unique.

Thus, if $f_n$ converges weakly to $h$ in $L_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ and converges pointwise to $g$ a.e, it follows that $f=g$ almost everywhere.

---

More sledgehammers:

For $p=1$ with a finite measure space:

Weak convergence of $\{f_n\}$ insures that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable. This is known as the 
Dunford-Pettis theorem
(see, e.g., pg. 59 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=40ovrqMqvqoC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=Dunford+Pettis+Theorem&source=bl&ots=tdLfSxENsH&sig=pvzb5PanbcxDsT-t4Y7iPkQwltg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v54gT5PdBYvpgAfEsLWMCQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBjgU#v=onepage&q=Dunford%20Pettis%20Theorem&f=false) or IV.8.11 in Dunford and Schwartz' *Linear Operators, Part 1, General Theory*). By the [Vitali Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) (see also page 163 
[here](http://www.math.byu.edu/~klkuttle/lecturenotes641.pdf)), then, $\{f_n\}$ converges to $g$ in $L_1$. Then, since convergence in norm to $g$ implies weak convergence to $g$, we must have $g=h$ a.e. .

Comment: Thank you so very much, David!!

Comment: David. Just to make sure I understood your second(last) answer: Can we conclude $g=h$ a.e. if $ f_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$ and $f_n$ converges to $h$ a.e.? Thanks!

Comment: @SarahGrady I think that would be a different problem (but it's true, since norm convergence to $g$ implies the existence of an a.e. convergent subsequence to $g$).  In the second argument above, it was shown that $f_n$ converges to $g$ in $L_1$. Then $f_n$ converges to $g$ weakly; and since weak limits are unique, we must have $g=h$ a.e..

Answer (score 6):

I will assume $1<p<\infty$. Since we work on a finite measure space, we can use Egoroff's theorem. Fix $\phi\in L^q$ where $q$ is the conjugate exponent (i.e. $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$). Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(A)\leq \delta$ then $\int_A |\phi|^q\leq \varepsilon^q$. Thanks to Egoroff's theorem, we can find $A_{\delta}$ such that $f_n\to g$ uniformly on $A_{\delta}$ and $\mu(A_{\delta}^c)\leq \delta$. So 
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_X(g-h)\phi ~d\mu\right|&\leq \limsup_n \left(\left|\int_X(g-f_n)\phi ~d\mu \right| +\left|\int_X(f_n-h)\phi ~ d\mu \right| \right)\\\
&\leq \limsup_n\left|\int_X(g-f_n)\phi ~ d\mu \right|\\\
&\leq \limsup_n\left(\left|\int_{A_{\delta}}(g-f_n)\phi ~ d\mu \right|+\left|\int_{A_{\delta}^c}(g-f_n)\phi ~d\mu \right|\right)\\\
&\leq \limsup_n\:\sup_{A_{\delta}}|g-f_n|\left(\int_X|\phi|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac 1q}+\sup_k\lVert g-f_k\rVert_{L^p}\left(\int_{A_{\delta}}|\phi|^q\right)^{\frac 1q}\\\
&\leq \varepsilon\cdot \sup_k\lVert g-f_k\rVert_{L^p}
\end{align*} 
so $\int_X(g-h)\phi d\mu=0$ for all $\phi \in L^q$: we conclude that $g=h$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much Davide!!

Comment: I think this argument can be simplified: By the uniform convergence $f_n \to g$ on $A_\delta$, we already get $g = h$ a.e. on $A_\delta$ (since $f_n \rightharpoonup h$ in $L^p(A_\delta)$).