# Example for weak convergence in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$-Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

We had in the lecture the following example for weak convergence to 0:
$f_k(x) = {k^{-n/2}} f(x/k)$, where $f \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$  fixed and $f$ has support in the unit ball $B_1(0)$.
Somehow I don't see why that is true.
I tried to use Hölder but did not get the desired result.
I'd be happy to get some hints (I think the $n=1$ case suffices).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it in the following way. Note that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f_k(x)|^2\leq\int_{|x|\le k}k^{-n}\|f\|_\infty\le C$$

where $C$ is a positive constant, hence, we can assume without loss of generality that $f_k$ does cnverge weak to some function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

On the other hand, note that for each fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} k^{-n/2}f(x/k)=0,$$

therefore, we have two facts about $f_k$, to wit, it converges to $0$ a.e. and it convergers weakly to some function $f$. To conclude, you can use this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611997/weak-and-almost-everywhere-convergence).

Comment: The first fact ist just $L^p$-boundedness, isn't it? I did not know that bounded sequences are weakly convergent; is that really true? We just had the reverse direction.

Comment: In fact, every bounded sequence in a reflexive space, has a subsequence which converges to some function in the weak topology. This is not the same as to say that the whole sequence converge, so the question is: why do I said that? There is a argument here. I will leave it to you think more, then if you need, post here comment that I give you the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** weak konvergence to $0$ means that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_k\overline gd\lambda\to 0,\ n\to\infty$ for every $g\in L^2(\mathbb R^n).$ It is enough to consider a dense subset of $g$'s. Take e.g. $g\in C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ - continuous with compact support.

Comment: I had a similar approach. This one leads to: $k^{-n/2} \int_{[a,b]}f(x/k) g(x) = k^{-n/2} \int_{[a,b]}( |f(x/k)|^2)^{1/2} ||g(x)||_2 =k^{-n/2} k^{n/2} \int_{[a/k,b/k ]}( |f(x)|^2)^{1/2} ||g(x)||_2 = \int_{[a/k,b/k \]}( |f(x)|^2)^{1/2} ||g(x)||_2 \to 0$ So I am done. Is there any mistake? Another thing is that I did not know that $C_c$ is dense in $L^2$. How can I see that? (But I know that it suffices to see the thing for a dense subset)

Comment: The first equation is obviously $\leq$, sorry (by Hölder). Later on I used the Transformation Theorem. I could not edit my comment anymore to change that stuff.